# proper usage of glob()

Tags: php

Is this the correct way to us glob() i'm trying to do a case insensitive search for the folder **TestFolder** on the server.

```
$chid = "testFoLdER";
$dirchk2 = "/temp/files/" . glob('".$chid."') . "/" . $data[1] . ".doc";
```

**@code_burgar** I made these changes to apply to the example code_burgar showed me. is this correct?
what i'm trying to do here is what ever globistr find for casing, rename the folder to lowercase.

```
$chid = (strtolower($_POST['chid']));
$findbatch = globistr($chid);
$results = glob($findbatch);

if ( !empty($results) ) {
  $result = $results[0];
  rename("/temp/files/" . $results . "/", "/temp/files/" . strtolower($chid) . "/");
} 
else 
{
    $missing_dir = 'Folder containing files, Not Found: ' . $chid . "\r";
    $errfile = fopen("/rec/" . $chid . "-errlog.txt", "a");
        fwrite($errfile, $missing_dir . "\n");
        fclose($errfile);
        exit();                           
}
```

Comment: Nope. http://www.php.net/glob has some examples

Answer (score 1):

That is most definitely not the way to use `glob()`. `glob()` returns an array and you are trying to use it in string concatenation.

As Pekka pointed out, PHP man page for glob has some case-insensitive example code.

What you are looking for basically is something along these lines (globistr() comes from PHP man page comments):

```
$chid = globistr("testFoLdER");
$results = glob($chid);

if ( !empty($results) ) {
  $result = $results[0];
  $dirchk2 = "/temp/files/" . $result . "/" . $data[1] . ".doc";
} else {
  echo('Not found');
}
```

Comment: Hi i followed you example as best as i could. can you take a look at my coding in my original post please, thanks.

Comment: Copy the function from the first comment on http://www.php.net/glob it's not a native php function.

Answer (score 1):

As workaround you can search all folder inside  **/temp/files/** that contain **$data[1]. '.doc'** file and then loop through results to make case-insensitive check if path contains your folder.

```
$file = "/temp/files/*/".$data[1].".doc";
$locations = glob($file);
$found = false;

foreach($locations as $l){
    if(stripos($l,'/testfolder/') !== false){
        $found = $l;
        break; 
    }
}
```